# display specific data called from api in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, api

this is going to be a really easy question, but quite frankly I can't word it well enough to discover the answer on my own. I should be able to roll forward with an answer.

```
client.getWalletBalance({coin: 'ETH'})
  .then(result => {
    console.log(result.ETH.available_balance);
    var availableBal = result;
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.error(err);
  });

later in the code: 

'wallet balance:' + availableBal + ' ETH'
```

TypeError: Cannot read property 'available_balance' of undefined

and

ReferenceError: availableBal is not defined

---

Here's the Response Example

```
{
    "ret_code": 0,
    "ret_msg": "OK",
    "ext_code": "",
    "ext_info": "",
    "result": {
        "ETH": {
            "equity": 1002,                         //equity = wallet_balance + unrealised_pnl
            "available_balance": 999.99987471,      //available_balance
            "used_margin": 0.00012529,              //used_margin = wallet_balance - available_balance
            "order_margin": 0.00012529,             //Used margin by order
            "position_margin": 0,                   //position margin
            "occ_closing_fee": 0,                   //position closing fee
            "occ_funding_fee": 0,                   //funding fee
            "wallet_balance": 1000,                 //wallet balance. When in Cross Margin mod, the number minus your unclosed loss is your real wallet balance.
            "realised_pnl": 0,                      //daily realized profit and loss
            "unrealised_pnl": 2,                    //unrealised profit and loss
            "cum_realised_pnl": 0,                  //total relised profit and loss
            "given_cash": 0,                        //given_cash
            "service_cash": 0                       //service_cash
        }
    },
    "time_now": "1578284274.816029",
    "rate_limit_status": 98,
    "rate_limit_reset_ms": 1580885703683,
    "rate_limit": 100
}
```

essentially im trying to pick the certain part of the response, set it as a variable and reuse it later on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've missing a `.result` there.
`result.result.ETH.available_balance`.

You may got confused because you variable is also named `result`.

Comment: awesome, thanks. this did solve the initial question. lastly, im trying to set it as a variable instead of console logging it to reuse later. have a say? :)

Comment: `let my_awsome_available_balance = result.result.ETH.available_balance`? I'm not really sure what you mean.

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/djKyOsV.png here's a visual of what im trying to pull off

Comment: You've to put the whole stuff within the `then(result => {` body. `client.getWalletBalance({coin: 'ETH'})` seems to be an async function this means that you'll not directly receive a result.